# In iOS Safari, cookie data gets destroyed on closing browser from background. I don't want to lose cookie data on closing the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I'm using jQuery Mobil & .Net to develop a mobile website. I'm storing authentication token in cookie when user checks "keep me logged in", so next time there is no need to log-in. But when I close the browser from background in iPhone cookie file exist but there is no data in it.

Comment: Switch to localstorage, cookies are thing of the past. Apple will also soon abandon cookies so abandon that old technology.

Comment: @Gajotres: "Apple will also soon abandon cookies" - do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Switching "Private navigation" off on the iphone did help.